# Funcion python Obtener los numeros reversos en una lista

Tags: python

Buenos Dias estoy intentando crear un funcion que reciba como argumento una lista y devuelta los numeros reversos de esa lista y aceptando solo aquellos q no sean mayor o igual q 50. Es decir, dada la lista `L=[ 4, 32, 20, 35,80,54]` la funcion deberia devolver como resultado  `[40,23,2,8,45]` (4 es 04 por lo tanto su reverso es 40 por lo que esta incluido, 32 su reverso es 23 por lo que esta incluido , 20 su reverso es 2 por lo que esta incluido, 35 su reverso es 53 no esta inclido, 80 su reverso es 8 esta incluido, 54 su reverso es 45 esta incluido).

mi funcion es la siguiente:

```
listas = [12, 23, 45, 56, 67, 68]
resultado_listas_invertidos = []


def invertir(lista_invertido):

    for invertido in lista_invertido:
        a = invertido
        x = 0

    y = (a % 10 == 0)
    z = len(str(a))
    for i in range(z):
        b = a % 10
        a = a//10
        x = x*10+b
        if i < 50:
            resultado_listas_invertidos.append(i)
    if y:
        x = str(x)
        x = '0'+x
        if i < 50:
            resultado_listas_invertidos.append(i)

    return list(resultado_listas_invertidos)


print(invertir(listas))
```

Comment: Hola! Cuál es tu pregunta? Qué problema tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo demasiados ciclos innecesarios, en tu primer ciclo, la variable `a` toma el ultimo valor de tu lista, luego estas iterando según la longitud del numero, lo cual es totalmente innecesario. Obviamente tu función no da el resultado esperado y solo devuelve `[0,1]`.

Podemos simplificar mucho tu código. Solo necesitamos 1 `for` el cual se encargará de recorrer los elementos de la lista, luego podemos crear una función que se encargue de obtener el reverso de un solo numero, si el numero es de una cifra tendremos que agregarle un `0` al final, algo así `x+"0"` pero esto con el numero convertido a cadena, luego tendremos que convertirlo a entero otra vez `int(x+"0")`, si el numero tiene mas de 1 cifra, entonces podemos usar la notación de *slice* para obtener sus caracteres de forma invertida, `[::-1]` recuerda que esto se puede usar para cualquier iterable, podemos convertir el numero (en forma de string) a una lista, pero luego tendremos que volver a juntar sus elementos, dado que un string también es un iterable podemos hacer `x[::-1]` y así obtendremos su *reverso*.

Para este caso utilicé una comprensión de lista para recorrer la lista de numeros, pero puedes hacerlo con un `for` normal.

```py
#funcion para invertir el numero
def invertir(num):
    num = str(num)
    #si es de una cifra
    if len(num) == 1: return int(f"{num}0")

    #retornamos las cifras en forma invertida
    return int(num[::-1])

#recorremos la lista y aplicamos la funcion para cada elemento
lista_invertida = [invertir(x) for x in lista if invertir(x)<50]
print(lista_invertida)
```

**resultado**

```
[40, 23, 2, 8, 45]
```

El `if invertir(x)<50` significa que solo agregaremos el elemento si el numero invertido es menor de `50`.

Comment: 1) la compresión de listas está fuera de la función 2)si agregas un número de tres cifras por ejemplo 123 a la lista, también te lo agregará y evidentemente es mayor a 50

Comment: no entiendo por que debería de estar dentro de una función, como expliqué, la función `invertir` solo se encarga de invertir un numero, y no es la encargada de realizar todo el proceso. En cuanto a lo otro ya lo corregí

Comment: no es que "debería" cada uno escribe código como quiere pero quien formuló la pregunta obtiene todo desde la función, con ese criterio tampoco entenderás porque puede haber un número de 3 o más cifras, lo cual me lleva a que nunca reconocés un error, corregís como si nada.

Comment: solo seguí el principio de responsabilidad única, para que cada parte del código se encargue de una cosa, el OP puede tomar mi código y hacer su propia implementación según como desee. Solo trato de simplificar la solución

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, intentas invertir el número como tal sin pasarlo a cadena,el problema es que en algún momento necesitarás str() como en tu código, pero se puede y ahorrando código:

```
listas =[ 4, 32, 20, 35,80,54]

def invertir(lista):
    invertida=[]
```

declaramos la lista que se devolverá en la propia función

```
for num in lista:
    x , z = divmod(num,10)
```

python trae la función divmod que te ahorra obtener el módulo y el resto

```
    res = int(str(z)+str(x))
```

para unir lo obtenido debo pasarlo primero a cadena

```
    if res < 50:
        invertida.append(res)
return invertida
```

esto ya es simple si el resultado es menor a 50 lo agregamos

```
print(invertir(listas))
```

Lo que devuelve:

```
[40, 23, 2, 8, 45]
```

El código de una:

```
listas =[ 4, 32, 20, 35,80,54]

def invertir(lista):
    invertida=[]
    for num in lista:
        x , z = divmod(num,10)
        res = int(str(z)+str(x))
        if res < 50:
            invertida.append(res)
    return invertida

print(invertir(listas))
```

Obviamente se puede convirtiendo cada número de la lista a cadena, pero no parece que es lo que buscas.

Comment: sabes que no es necesario obtener el resto?

Comment: @Christian ahhh ¿no? bueno omitilo eliminando z y contame como te va

Comment: jeje, pues bien, y ti?, como te va?

Comment: @Christian ¿a mi? barbaró! esperando tu código sin el resto.

Comment: mi código no obtiene ni obtendrá el resto, se puede simplificar todo con un simple `if`

Comment: tu código es funcional ahora después de corregirlo , no quita que si usas divmod hay que usar el resto, que es lo que me planteaste.

Comment: Haa bueno, no te preocupes, un problema tiene varias soluciones, yo solo busqué una simplificada

Comment: no me preocupo, soy uno de los primeros en plantear que hay diversas formas de enfocar un problema, pero de ahí a un planteo sin sentido sobre un código hay mucha diferencia.

Comment: gracias es lo que necesitaba